# Adding an image to Firebase

Tags: image, listview, firebase-storage

I have a firebase database where the user can add name and description. The name and description then appear in a list-view. I want to add a third element to this where the user can add a photo and display it in an image view. 
I do not know how to add a photo to firebase can somebody help me.

Here is what I have so far :

my model class: (should I add the image here?)

```
public class Recipe {
    private String recipeId;
    private String recipeName;
    private String recipeDescription;

public String getRecipeId() {
    return recipeId;
}

public void setRecipeId(String recipeId) {
    this.recipeId = recipeId;
}

public void setRecipeName(String recipeName) {
    this.recipeName = recipeName;
}

public void setRecipeDescription(String recipeDescription) {
    this.recipeDescription = recipeDescription;
}

public Recipe(String recipeId, String recipeName, String recipeDescription) {
    this.recipeId = recipeId;

    this.recipeName = recipeName;
    this.recipeDescription = recipeDescription;
}



public String getRecipeName() {
    return recipeName;
}

public String getRecipeDescription() {
    return recipeDescription;
}

public Recipe(){

    //this constructor is required
}
```

my listview class

```
public class RecipeList extends ArrayAdapter<Recipe> {
    private Activity context;
    List<Recipe> recipes;

public RecipeList(Activity context, List<Recipe> recipes) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_recipe_list, recipes);
    this.context = context;
    this.recipes = recipes;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recipe_list, null, true);

    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textViewDescription = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);

    Recipe recipe = recipes.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(recipe.getRecipeName());
    textViewDescription.setText(recipe.getRecipeDescription());

    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

my main fragment where i want to upload the image

```
public class AddRecipeFragment extends Fragment {

//we will use these constants later to pass the artist name and id to another activity
public static final String RECIPE_NAME = "net.simplifiedcoding.firebasedatabaseexample.artistname";
public static final String RECIPE_ID = "net.simplifiedcoding.firebasedatabaseexample.artistid";

//view objects
EditText editTextName;
EditText editTextDescription;
Button buttonAddRecipe;
ListView listViewRecipes;

ProgressBar progressBar;


FirebaseAuth mAuth;


//a list to store all the foods from firebase database
List<Recipe> recipes;

//our database reference object
DatabaseReference databaseRecipes;


public AddRecipeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment AddRecipeFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static AddRecipeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    AddRecipeFragment fragment = new AddRecipeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


    //getting the reference of artists node
    databaseRecipes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("recipes");


    databaseRecipes.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //clearing the previous artist list
            recipes.clear();

            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //getting artist
                Recipe recipe = postSnapshot.getValue(Recipe.class);
                //adding artist to the list
                //     recipes.add(recipe);
            }

            //creating adapter
            RecipeList recipeAdapter = new RecipeList(getActivity(), recipes);
            //attaching adapter to the listview
            listViewRecipes.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}



public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //getting views
    editTextName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextDescription= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
    listViewRecipes = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewRecipes);
    buttonAddRecipe = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddRecipe);

    //list to store artists
    recipes = new ArrayList<>();

    //adding an onclicklistener to button
    buttonAddRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //calling the method addArtist()
            //the method is defined below
            //this method is actually performing the write operation
            addRecipe();
        }
    });


}



private void addRecipe() {

    //getting the values to save
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString().trim();

    //checking if the value is provided
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

        //getting a unique id using push().getKey() method
        //it will create a unique id and we will use it as the Primary Key for our Artist
        String id = databaseRecipes.push().getKey();

        //creating an Artist Object
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe(id, name, description);

        //Saving the Artist
        databaseRecipes.child(id).setValue(recipe);

        //setting edittext to blank again
        editTextName.setText("");

        //displaying a success toast
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "recipe added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        //if the value is not given displaying a toast
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a recipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_recipe, container, false);
}

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934) tutorial, It will provide you a good start.

This contains the basic code that is required. You need to assign the file path of the image to "filepath" variable mentioned in the code segment and call upload image method.

```
//Firebase
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;

storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
storageReference = storage.getReference();

private void uploadImage() {

  if(filePath != null)
  {

    StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    ref.putFile(filePath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                        .getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
              }
            });
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19101263)

Comment: Thank You for the advice. I'll change the answer :)